# Possible to have a statement in stored procedure outside of current transaction?

Tags: mysql

During a series of statements in my stored procedure I wish to log an entry by inserting a record. That record needs to survive even if the overall SP ends up rolling back.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282779/django-mysql-how-to-do-autonomous-transactions-commit-only-sub-set-of-querie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the log table to be `ENGINE=MyISAM`.